# Extract last number after decimal

Tags: java, json, regex, substring

I am getting a piece of JSON text from a url connection and saving it to a string currently as such:

```
...//setting up url and connection
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String str = in.readLine();
```

When I print str, I correctly find the data `{"build":{"version_component":"1.0.111"}}`

Now I want to extract the 111 from str, but I am having some trouble.

I tried 
`String afterLastDot = inputLine.substring(inputLine.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);`

but I end up with `111"}}`

I need a solution that is generic so that if I have `String str = {"build":{"version_component":"1.0.111111111"}};` the solution still works and extracts 111111111 (ie, I don't want to hard code extract the last three digits after the decimal point)

Comment: Hmm. so where are you using regex ?

Comment: You could do JSON

Comment: json.getBuild.getVersion_component

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make sense. Do you mean the whole thing is in a string? i.e. `"String str = {\"build\":{\"version_component\":\"1.0.111\"}};"` Or do you mean `String str = "{\"build\":{\"version_component\":\"1.0.111\"}};"`

Comment: String value must start with " and end with "

Comment: how about some replace to replace the trailing `}`s and quote

Comment: It doesn't make sense even now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use a JSON parser then you can this regex based extraction:

```
String lastNum = str.replaceAll("^.*\\.(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EzVLtx/2)

`^.*` is greedy match that matches everything until last DOT and 1 or more digits that we put in group #1 to be used in replacement.

Comment: what if str contains 1.0.111 more then once?

Comment: @user648026: OP wants to extract *last number after decimal*

Answer (score 0):

just use JSON api

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
String versionComponent= obj.getJSONObject("build").getString("version_component");
```

Then just split and take the last element

```
versionComponent.split("\\.")[2];
```

Comment: That's wrong. First of all the `str` in his code makes 0 sense !

Comment: Plus you give 1.0.111

Answer (score 0):

Find the `start` and the `end` indexes of the String you need and `substring(start, end)`  :

```
// String str = "{"build":{"version_component":"1.0.111"}};" cannot compile without escaping
String str = "{\"build\":{\"version_component\":\"1.0.111\"}}";

int start = str.lastIndexOf(".")+1;
int end = str.lastIndexOf("\"");
String substring = str.substring(start,end);
```

Comment: what if str contains 1.0.111 more then once?

Answer (score 0):

Please, your can try the following code :
...
int index = inputLine.lastIndexOf(".")+1 ;
String afterLastDot = inputLine.substring(index, index+3);

Answer (score -1):

With Regular Expressions (Rexp),
You can solve your problem like this ;

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("111") ;
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str) ;
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.start()+" "+matcher.end());
    System.out.println(str.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in hard-coding an answer as stated in my question